# How to echo javascript code which contains php tags inside?

Tags: php

I usually echo script alert by simply

`echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("'.$my_message.'");</script>';`
but how to echo the script when the script contains php tags? (see my example code)

Because of my php obfuscator script, I have to use only one `<?php` `?>` tag. so in this case I need to echo the javascript without having `<?php` tags. What are the possible solutions in this case?

```
    <?php 
...some php code...
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $i = 0;
        $('.wrapper_vertical_menu .megamenu_menu').append('<div class="more-wrap"><span class="more"><?php echo $this->__("More"); ?></span></div>');
        $('.wrapper_vertical_menu .megamenu_menu > li.megamenu_lv1').each(function(){
            $i ++; 
            if($i>13){ 
                $(this).css('display', 'none');
            }           
        });
        ... more js code ...
```

Comment: "Ditch the obfuscator" would be my favorite solution.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript doesn't "contain PHP tags".  All your PHP code needs to do is build the resulting output string (which happens to be JavaScript code, but that doesn't matter to PHP) and echo it.

So where you have something like this:

```
echo "some javascript code <?php echo some_php_value; ?> more javascript code";
```

What you really want, quite simply, is this:

```
echo "some javascript code " . some_php_value . " more javascript code";
```

Don't try to nest `<?php ?>` tags within each other.  Just concatenate the actual output you want and echo that output.

Comment: @Davind Thanks. This line of code `echo $this->__("More");` is required for Magento translation class. I am not sure if $this->__() is a simple variable.

Comment: @R.Toward: It must resolve to some printable value if that value is being meaningfully echoed to the output.  Just concatenate that value into your output.  The point is, PHP code doesn't need to *contain* PHP code.  It already *is* PHP code.